# Тип элементов вектора. С++

Tags: c++

`std::vector<type>` насколько я понимаю , написав определенный type, то элементами моего вектора могут быть только этого типа. А можно ли сделать так , чтобы элементы вектора(в одном и том же векторе)были разного типа. Например флоат и целочисленные?

Comment: [std::any](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)

Comment: Один из вариантов:  Если  type2*  может неявно преобразится в   type1*, то гда  можно хранить в векторе  указатели  type1*.

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan А как это записать ?

Comment: Нет, элементы vector могут быть только одного типа. При хранении элементов `std::any` или `std::variant` или `void *` элементы vector все равно будет одного и того же типа, независимо от типа данных, которые в них оборачиваются.

Answer (score 4):

Можно воспользоватся std::variant: `std::vector<std::variant<type1,type2>>`.

```
std::vector <std::variant<int, float>> vec {1,4.5f,45,4.9f};
std::cout << std::get<int>(vec[0]) << " - " << std::get<float>(vec[1]) 
<< " - " << std::get<int>(vec[2]) << " - " << std::get<float>(vec[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

По любому вектор должен содержать обьекты одного типа. `std::vector<type>`  является оберткой для массива, хранящийся `type`, знающий размер этого массива, имеющий функциональности. Другое дело, что этот самый `type` может быть типом, указанным от пользователья `mrFieldy` или другим подобным. Или же он может быть типом указателем. В таком случаи он может принимать значение адреса любого обьекта типа, чей указатель может неявно преобразится в `type*`. Например:

```
struct Type1 {
    float f;
    Type1(float k = .0f) : f(k) {}
};

struct Type2 : Type1 {
    Type2(int i = 0) : Type1(i){}
};
```

Так как `Type2` является наследником структуры  `Type1`(строится на ее основе), то  Type1*  может указывать и на  обьекты `Type2`. Поэтому мы можем спокойно записать такую программу:

```
vector<Type1*> v;
Type1 fn = 0.4;
Type2 in = 3;
v.push_back(&fn);
v.push_back(&in);
cout << v[0]->f << '\t' << v[1]->f;
```

Comment: Реально в данном примере мы имеем `vector<float>`. Все остальные пляски с классами демонстрируют иерархию инкапсуляций функций для инициализации

Comment: @avp, вы правы, это всего лишь демонстрация, кстати, по просьбе автора вопроса

Comment: Насколько я понял вопрос, его интересуют реально разные типы в одном векторе. *`"Например флоат и целочисленные"`*

Comment: смотрите в комментариях